# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] path not working in my html link

Tags: php

I am getting the expected return with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], but when i click the link, the string the constant contains is just appending to the web address already there.

For instance i have :

```
define("ROOT_PATH",$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/webroot/mysite/');
```

then later a link (intended for the root of my site)

```
$hud .= '<a href="'.ROOT_PATH.'" class="nav_links">Home</a>';
```

I click the link it gives me this error:

The requested URL /**mysite**/home/content/39/11607339/html/**mysite**/includes was not found on this server.

Can someone tell me why it is just appending to the url rather than normal behavior which is just go to that file?

Comment: put `http://` before the `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`

Comment: What does `print_r()` say is in `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`? What does it say is in `ROOT_PATH`?

Comment: You cannot access your local filesystem using anchor tags in your HTML. You should use file:/// instead if you wish to do so . . .

Comment: you can use `/` for root, `'<a href="/ ' . ROOT_PATH . ' " class="nav_links">Home</a>'`

Comment: print_r() and var_dump say the same thing - the path from somewhere 
(on my hosting account) to the url - if I could get the browser to navigate to that path on the click of the link instead of appending to the end of whats already there it would be great.

Comment: I would like to try the file:/// suggestion, but im not sure what he means.

Answer (score 3):

try `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in define function.

Comment: This works for the home link that i provided however, my icons are still not showing up. My whole purpose for doing this is so i can use it on my sub-domains, if not ide just stick with relative paths.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
define("ROOT_PATH", 'http://' . $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/webroot/mysite/');
```

Comment: Still appending the path rather than navigating to it. :/